# In Python how to capture Redshift's response on COPY command?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I used SQLAlchemy + PyGreSQL to send COPY command to Redshift to import CSV/JSON files into database tables.  After COPY command was executed, a message line was sent back on screen:

```
INFO:  Load into table 'o_item_details' completed, 20443 record(s) loaded successfully.
```

How do I capture this message so I can push it into logging function which writes logs to files?  Here's my code:

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql+pygresql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}".format(rs_user, rs_pwd, rs_host, rs_port, rs_dbname))
conn = engine.connect()
re = conn.execute(sql_cmd)
```

`sql_cmd` is the COPY statement (`copy {rs_tbl_name} from s3://{s3_bucket}/{s3_file} ...` )

I played around the ResultProxy object returned by execute function but didn't find a way to retrieve the message.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Since stackoverflow does not allow short answers, I had to add this sentence you are reading:)

`print(conn.notices)`

Comment: I tried but got below error message: `'Connection' object has no attribute 'notices'`   I did some research and maybe this attribute is available only in connection object created by `psycopg2`, not by SQLAlchemy's `create_engine`?

Comment: Absolutely! Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the connection provider you used. Correcting my post in a second.

Comment: Ok, after some digging: I have no idea how to do it in sqlalchemy with pygresql, it's probably way more complicated than it should. Your options:
1. Easiest way to get the information you need is running `select pg_last_copy_count()` right after your COPY command.
2. Second easiest: Migrate to plain pygresql instead of sqlalchemy. You can then use conn.getnotices().
3. Third way: install psycopg2 and use psycopg2 dialect in sqlalchemy. Use conn.notices from original answer. Not sure if it isn't easier than 2.

Comment: Sorry it took so long btw, but it turned out more complicated than it should, and life happens outside stack;)

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help me out.  I will try your option (2)  first but will require some work.  I inherited good chunk of codes from older projects and sqlalchemy is already embeded everywhere.  Option (1)  is definitely an universal solution, but sometimes our Redshift cluster's response is rather slow. :(